# How to write checkbox in flask?

Tags: python, checkbox, flask, jinja2

I want to render a template.In the template, I have a checkbox called "IsValid", its value is from database. I want to read and edit the state of checkbox. After edit the checkbox, I want to store the its value in the database. How should I write the checkbox?

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="IsValid" class="control-label col-md-2">IsValid</label>       
<div class="col-md-2">
    <input type="checkbox" class="form-control" id="IsValid" name="IsValid" {{ checked="checked" if items[6]=1 else "" }} " >
</div>
</div>
```

In the code, **items[6]** is passed by view function.It's value is from database, it has two values,0 and 1.

How to modify `{{ checked="checked" if items[6]=1 else "" }}`?

Because it is wrong.

> Wrong information:jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: expected
>   token 'end of print statement', got '='

I don't know if you can understand because my English is poor.

Comment: Check out (pun intended) https://gist.github.com/doobeh/4668212

Answer (score 9):

Your jinja2 syntax is not correct.
    `<input type="checkbox" class="form-control" id="IsValid" name="IsValid" {% if items[6]==1 %}checked{% else %}{% endif %}>`

Comment: The `{% else %}` is unnecessary here. `{% if items[6]==1 %}checked{% endif %}` suffices.

Comment: Thank you so much .I search this answer for long days. Now only I got it.